# What does "知らないより" mean here?

Tags: translation

I was watching this Japanese drama called *Nagareboshi* where a girl confessed her feelings for some guy but regrets not having said her feelings sooner. Her lines confuse me. It was something like this.

> でもこれで良かったのかもね...
>   私のみっともない所見せられたから...
>   きっと知らないよりは...
>   少しだけ長く一緒にいられる気がする...

Only thing I can really understand is the 1st line, "It might better this way."
I think the 2nd line goes like "If you saw how shameful I am.."

The 3rd and 4th lines I'm having trouble with the most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

より is a comparison target marker. より can directly follow a verb/adjective, for example, 作るより食べる方が好きです ("I like eating more than preparing food"), ないよりある方がいい ("Having some is better than having nothing."). So 知らないより literally means "rather than not knowing", "compared to his not knowing (my true self)".

> 私のみっともない所見せられたから...
>   ...because I was able to show him the shameful part of myself.
>
> きっと知らないよりは...
>   Perhaps, compared to the case where he did not know it,
>
> 少しだけ長く一緒にいられる気がする...
>   (with this,) I feel I can be with him a little bit longer.